# I'm facing a TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, charts

Hi I'm trying to create a horizontal bar chart using flask and facing the following error. TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement. Please help. Thanks in advance.

app.py
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request, flash, session
import pandas as pd
app = Flask(**name**)
app.debug = True

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
            return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/data', methods=['GET','POST'])
def dropdown():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.form['upload-file']
        data = pd.read_excel(file)
        data = pd.DataFrame(data)
        colours=data['Question'].unique().tolist()
        return render_template('test.html', colours=colours)

@app.route("/data/submitted", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def charts():
    #select = request.form.get('colour')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        to_filter = request.form.get['colours']
        # filter the data here
        plot_data = data[data['Themes'].str.contains(to_filter)]
        plot_data['flag'] = 1
        plot_data2 = plot_data.groupby(['Themes'])['flag'].sum().reset_index()
        #colours1 = data1['Question'].unique().tolist()
        labels = plot_data2['Themes'].tolist()
        values = plot_data2['flag'].tolist()
        bar_labels = labels
        bar_values = values
        return render_template("sample_chart1.html", labels=bar_labels,data=bar_values)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

sample_chart1.html

```
<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Charts.js</title>
  <!-- import plugin script -->
</head>

<h1>Chart</h1>
<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
<!-- bar chart canvas element -->
<canvas id="chart" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
<p id="caption">Distribution of Topics.</p>

<script>

// create the chart using the chart canvas

var chartData = {
  labels : [{% for item in labels %}
             "{{item}}",
            {% endfor %}],
  datasets : [{
      data : [{% for item in values %}
                {{item}},
              {% endfor %}],
      spanGaps: false
  }]
}

// get chart canvas
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'horizontal bar',
  data: chartData,
});

</script>
```

Comment: I dont have any experience with flas but the error says it all. The routes /data and /data/submitted does not return anything if it was a get call. You are returning respose only for post calls and seems like you are doing a get call.

Answer (score 2):

It is making a GET request, which does not pass the `if request.method == 'POST'`
And since it does not pass there is no return for requests that aren't POST

Comment: I have used ' if request.method == 'POST' ' still getting the same error

Comment: @Soutir Try to set a return statement at the same indentation as the `if request.method == 'POST'`